# Any way to upload Flutter local aar maven repository to remote maven repository?

Tags: android, flutter, maven

After we use `flutter build aar` cmd and get local maven repository. Any way to push these aar to remote maven repository?

I have tried this cmd
`find . -name "*.pom" -type f -exec sh -c 'mvn deploy:deploy-file -DpomFile="$0" -Dfile="${0%.pom}.aar"' '{}' \;`
But got following error

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The parameters 'file', 'url' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0:deploy-file are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here is the one way I have tried. Instead of creating the local repo it will directly upload the generated files to the maven.

Update **aar_init_script.gradle** located inside the installed flutter_tools file as shown.
Save the file and run the command

```
flutter build aar --build-number [version_name] --no-profile --no-release
```

Example:

```
flutter build aar --build-number 1.0.12 --no-profile --no-release
```